# Mongoose validation error - what is it telling me?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use a JSON file to populate my DB - I've had success with some other files, but this file / model is throwing validation errors and the errors aren't very helpful to me - They say there is a validation error, they even kinda tell me that it's at a forEach line in the schematype.js file - but I'm not gonna go and change a file in the node-modules folder...especially when I think it's my coding fault.

"mongoose": "4.9.8"

This is in the APP.JS - which calls  /loaddata:

```
app.get('/api/loadData', (req, res) => {
    var Xs = require( './_mock_data/x.json' );

    for ( var i in Xs ) {

        X.create( Xs[i] );
        console.log( Xs[i] );

    };

});
```

This is in my model page:

```
const XSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    state:{
        type: String
    },
    type:{
        type: String
    },
    people:{
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

My JSON file looks like this - I think the offending data is the "people" with a Mixed type - my confusion comes with the fact that it IS an array of people, so the forEach should loop it - why is it failing?

```
[
    {
        "name": "Building One",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "people": [{
            "position": "Chair",
            "department": "Sales",
            "email": "aftcs@blah.io",
            "phone": "",
            "name": "John Smith"
        }],
        "type": "Business"
    }, {
        "name": "Fairbanks Folly",
        "state": "Maine",
        "people": [{
            "position": "Sitting",
            "department": "AAA",
            "email": "ffjda@uafert.com",
            "phone": "",
            "name": "Jane Aspnes"
        }, {
            "position": "Standing",
            "department": "BBB",
            "email": "jmbicigo@Maine.com",
            "phone": "",
            "name": "James Bicigo"
        }, {
            "position": "Lying",
            "department": "AAA",
            "email": "kmbutlerhopkins@Craf.org",
            "phone": "",
            "name": "Kam Butler-Hopkins"
        }],
        "type": "Other"
    }
]
```

And lastly - the ERROR -

```
Unhandled rejection ValidationError: College validation failed
    at new ValidationError (C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:23:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1629:32)
    at C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1501:17
    at validate (C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:733:7)
    at C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:778:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:738:19)
    at C:\MyProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1499:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Again, any help and insight is much appreciated!

Comment: you have any schema named college?

Comment: Ya...I added that "people" and "type" - sorry i just noticed my example didn't reflect that - the names are the same in the schema and the JSON.

Comment: do they have to be in the same order? - my data has the type as the last element, but my schema it is not last.. that shouldn't make a difference, should it? JSON is name:value, so the names should be 'checked' not the position.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me. The data doesn't have to be in a specific order.

Comment: Ya - on closer inspection - it is inserting about 90% - there are certain records that are causing an issue - and my frustration is the error message isn't at all informative about what failed. just where in the parsing code...so I'd have to compare inserted to full file to find the offending data.